# Trunk-based development release & hotfix questions

Tags: git, version-control, branching-strategy

I'm having trouble to understand how to deal with the following scenario:

1. Feature A is committed to `master` as commit `A`.
2. We are ready for release `v1.0.0` so we tag commit `A` as `v1.0.0` and we create a release branch `rel-1.0.x` from it for QA.
3. Feature B is committed to `master` as commit `B`.
4. QA approves `v1.0.0`, we deploy and delete the `rel-1.0.x` branch.
5. We are ready for release `v2.0.0` so we tag commit `B` as `v2.0.0` and create a `rel-2.0.x` branch from it for QA.
6. A bug is found in production (`v1.0.0`) and must be fixed and deployed right away.

At this point I'm not sure how we should handle that. If the bug is in the trunk we could create a hotfix branch from the trunk, fix the bug and merge into the trunk. Then, create a `rel-1.0.1` branch from `v1.0.0`, cherry-pick the fix from the trunk, tag it as `v1.0.1` and deploy.

Now what I find odd is that the `v1.0.1` commit is not as-is in `master` given it's been cherry-picked from `master` and tagged in the `rel-1.0.1` branch. Furthermore, if the fix is also needed in `rel-2.0.x` then how should we handle this? Should we cherry-pick the bug-fix from the trunk again and tag it as a different version, such as `v2.0.1`?

Here's the kind of graph I'd be getting doing the above (note that v1.1 represents version 2.0 of the text above and that it's the `Second feature A fix` that occurred while preparing the `v1.1` release.):

[image]

Comment: I dont get what bothers you with the approach you described. Seems fine to me

Comment: @Francesco It kinda feels weird to me that all versioned commits don't end up in `master` (e.g. v1.0.2 and v1.1.1)? Is that usual? I also often read that cherry-picks are to be avoided, but here I'll almost always cherry-pick bug fixes. It also annoys me that the introduction of the same fix yields two new hotfix version numbers. One for the currently released version and one for the release in preparation.

Comment: I have nothing against cherry picks. And I dont see anything wrong with release tags not in master. My suggestion is to do what works for you. Trunk based is great but It can be adapted. And there is no reason why you cannot change your flow after a bit of experience

Comment: If the hotfix branch also need to apply to your current release branch `rel-2.0`, it's ok merge or cherry-pick changes from `hotfix` to `rel-2.0` and then tag a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this question, it seems like my concerns were not founded and the versioning/tagging approach as well as the workflow described in the above question is acceptable and works just fine in practice.

One challenge I've faced though is when master incrementally diverges more and more from what's in production. This could happen for many reasons, such as having commits in master that were in theory ready to get released, but somehow didn't go in production. The way I've dealt with that problem is by continuously re-working the commit tree in production so that what diverges stays on top.

Answer (score 0):

Always pull your commits to master then cherry pick to release branch. All commits will then be in master